# How to call super from the lambda function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Currently, my approach to adding ItemDecorator (Android) to Adapter is this:

```kotlin
myAdapter.addItemDecoration(object : RecyclerView.ItemDecoration() {
                override fun getItemOffsets(
                    outRect: Rect,
                    view: View,
                    parent: RecyclerView,
                    state: RecyclerView.State
                ) {
                    super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
                    outRect.top = 10
                    outRect.bottom = 10
                    outRect.left = 10
                    outRect.right = 10
                }
            })
```

This looks very boilerplate-ish. Is it possible to do something like:

```kotlin
myAdapter.addItemDecoration{
outRect, view, parent, state -> super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state)
outRect.top = 10
outRect.bottom = 10
outRect.left = 10
outRect.right = 10
}
```

Comment: no you can't call super from lambda function if you want to do so you will need to use your first approach.

Comment: ItemDecoration is not a SAM type so you cannot implicitly convert it to a lambda. You're free to write your own extension function that will construct decoration based on a lambda.